# Why pymongo eval result is different from mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

When I execute "db.abc.find()" in mongo shell it returns the following answer:

```
 db.abc.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a942bfec926681f17f09b6"), "name" : "foo" }
```

But when I execute the same command via PyMongo's eval method I receive a different answer:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient()
>>> db = client.test
>>> db.eval('db.abc.find()')
{u'_special': False, u'_options': 0.0, u'_ns': u'test.abc', u'_db': {u'_mongo': {u'slaveOk': False, u'host': u'EMBEDDED'}, u'_name': u'test'}, u'_skip': 0.0, u'_numReturned': 0.0, u'_query': {}, u'_limit': 0.0, u'_mongo': {u'slaveOk': False, u'host': u'EMBEDDED'}, u'_collection': {u'_shortName': u'abc', u'_db': {u'_mongo': {u'slaveOk': False, u'host': u'EMBEDDED'}, u'_name': u'test'}, u'_mongo': {u'slaveOk': False, u'host': u'EMBEDDED'}, u'_fullName': u'test.abc'}, u'_cursor': None, u'_fields': None, u'_batchSize': 0.0}
```

What this is happening?
How to fix it?

Comment: why are you doing this, what you want to achive with eval() the evil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `eval()` is definitely evil and is [actually deprecated](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.eval).

You should wrap the code into a function to make it work:

```
from bson import Code

db.eval(Code('function () { return db.abc.find(); }'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you just call `db.abc.find()` from Python and get you document(s) from cursor?

```
[doc for doc in db.abc.find()]
```

Or still:

```
db.abc.find_one()
```